# Adjust UIImage size as per UIImageView size without losing its quality in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

I have one image of size **3264 × 2448** and an image view of size **768 × 1024**. I want to get an image size equal to the view's size without losing image quality.

I googled for it; `AspectFit` not giving me proper output. I tried the following code:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize: (CGSize)targetSize {

   UIImage *sourceImage = self;
   UIImage *newImage = nil;

   CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
   CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
   CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

   CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
   CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

   CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
   CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
   CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

   CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

   if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
       }
    }


    // this is actually the interesting part:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just assign `imageView.image = theImage;`? It will take care of the resizing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

specify your new size as (768,1024) and pass your original image, but make sure your height and width ratio of original image should be same as converted image ratio.

Comment: congratulations...Have a nice day...:)

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) article as reference for some of my projects included image resizing. UIImage+Resize category works pretty well except the significant performance hit until the resized version of image is created.

You may cache the resized version on disk to avoid resizing it again in future. Also I haven't tried yet but you can try resizing image in a background thread to avoid blocking the UI.

Comment: There are links to code in article but here is the UIImage+Resize for convenience: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.h http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage+Resize.m

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of the input image isnt a multiple of your `UIImageView`'s dimensions, and thats why aspectFit wont work here (will leave gaps on the sides most likely). if you use scaleToFill your image will warp because again your image dimensions are off. I think you will have to do something about the dimensions of one of these to preserve the image properly.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. So I'm trying to get ratio for uiimage. Is this right?